# vTiger Update an existing entry on the CRM object not working

Tags: php, permissions, access-denied, vtiger

I need to use the update Rest API (Data objects operations) to update the fields in the vTiger CRM,
but I am having this issue:

> Permission to perform the operation is denied for id

[image: update operation postman]

I am missing something? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

It's late but You need to share the full request so that I can check what parameters are wrong and if still getting errors.

I can give you a quick hint that you should check for the fields in which you have passed the record ID. As Vtiger has a specific format to pass record ID via API, you must have to follow that.

Example for Opportunity record ID: 13x3442424 whereas 13 is Module ID which is identified from vtiger_ws_entity based on Module name.

Comment: Hi @Milan, I am getting the particular record of Sales Order as id=15x1234, being 1234 is my Sales Order id. Can you please tell me the way from which I can get the complete list of Sales Order, not a particulat Sales Order?

Comment: @MuhammadNoman You can use Sync Operation API to get list of all records. https://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/third-party-app-integration.html#sync-operation

Comment: Hi @MilanMalani, I am facing the similar issue. I am using record_id as "12*contact_id" for Contact module, but stii getting the same error! How to resolve this issue?

Comment: @KiszNa, If you are trying with "12*contact_id" then its wrong. You have to try with "12xcontact_id". Not * but use x (small letter x)